# Importing module with different class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a module named jaguar which has different classes under it. Each class has many functions inside it. When I import the whole module by

```
import jaguar as jg
```

and then try to call a function named read_excel, it is showing error as

```
AttributeError: module 'jaguar' has no attribute named 'read_excel'
```

Instead if I call each class by class and use it, it will work.

Could someone please help me to sort out the issue?

Comment: Show your code. And only use relevant tags: this doesn't seem to have anything to do with Pandas.

Comment: Is `read_excel` a *module-level* method or a method in one of the classes in `jaguar`? You can check with `dir(jg)`

Comment: @C.Nivs : it is one function created by me under a class named excel in jaguar module

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, it's difficult to be 100% certain what is happening. In the future, it is likely that you'll get more and better answers to your questions if you include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

It seems best to avoid details of how Python finds functions and methods when they are called (doubly so, since I'm no expert in this subject.) That said, it seems the issue is that you are trying to call a function as if it was defined at the module level. However, the function in question is actually a method defined within a class (inside that module). It seems you have a jaguar.py file structured something like:

```
""" jaguar module does jaguar-y stuff """
class TheClass:
    def __init__(self):
        # Do object initialization stuff
    def read_excel(self):
        print('In read_excel()')
```

And in your program file you're trying to do something like this:

```
""" main program """
import jaguar as jg
jg.read_excel()
```

Which will result in an [AttributeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#AttributeError) because the function is not found at the module level. Instead, you need to instantiate an object and then call the method:

```
""" main program """
import jaguar as jg
my_ob = jg.TheClass()
my_ob.read_excel()
```

Alternatively, you might be able to define the function at the module level - i.e. outside of classes - if that works for what you are trying to do. So jaguar.py would be structured something like:

```
""" jaguar module does jaguar-y stuff """
def read_excel():
    print('In read_excel()')

class TheClass:
    def __init__(self):
        # Do object initialization stuff
```

This latter example will allow you to call read_excel() via `jg.read_excel()`, as in the first main program example above.

You might find it helpful to go through the tutorial on [Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).